# How to uniquely identify each value of lightning select as well as button with same aura id

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Basically, I've created lightning select inside aura iteration , but how do i uniquely identify which specific value of each lightning select and button (upload) was clicked , as the buttons have the same label name and same aura Id (since it's inside a loop)

**Currently the value for all the lightning select becomes same, I want to select different values for every lightning select inside aura iteration**

Comment: give more information of what you are doing,anyway you can directly get which button you are pressing by using "event" https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm

Comment: You just place an attribute on a parent element, then you can identify the row uniquely. I've linked my own question that has a demonstration of the answer.